# Detect if an element is 60% off the right edge of screen in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Javascript's native drag, how can I detect when an object is 60% off the right edge of the screen / window. Meaning 40% of it is showing?

By 60%, I mean what is equal to 60% of the window's current width. So when the amount of 60% of the window's current width is hidden and 40% or less of the window's width is showing.

I need to have this as an if condition who's suite can be jQuery code.

What i've tried is using the Pep.js plugin and the first else if inside the drag option. That and the code is in more detail here: [jQuery code in if statement not running even though alert in if statement happens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17092672/2450243)

Comment: With a bit of math should be easy. Where's the issue, do you have some code to share?

Comment: If the dragging itself is an issue, I found [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cww55/6/) from my "archives". It's not exactly what you need, but you can strip the parts you don't need, and add your own...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I tried doing it in link to the question I updated this question with.

Comment: @DjangoJohnson You are wellcome. I've created that snippet for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12175176/1169519) of mine, just check the question, there's a commented pseudo code, which might help you to develope the code.

Comment: @Teemu It helps with the dragging. But how do I detect when an element is off the right edge of the screen / window. That is what I need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here it comes.

The script:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var AniMove = function (doc, element) {
        var ox, oy, mx, my,
            w = element.offsetWidth,
            mouseMove = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (element.offsetLeft + 0.4 * w > window.innerWidth) {
                    // 60% of the element's width is outside of the window now... do something
                    return;
                }               
                element.style.left = element.offsetLeft + e.clientX - mx + 'px';
                element.style.top = element.offsetTop + e.clientY - my + 'px';
                mx = e.clientX;
                my = e.clientY;
                return false;
            },
            mouseUp = function () {
                doc.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
                doc.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
                return;
            },
            mouseDown = function (e) {
                ox = mx = e.clientX;
                oy = my = e.clientY;
                doc.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
                doc.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
                return;
            };
        element.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    },
    drag = new AniMove(document, document.getElementById('square'));    
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="square"></div>
```

finally the CSS:

```
DIV {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

After all that done we have a [demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bcpf7/2/). I hope this snippet contains all the information you need.